# BackColor is not changing even though conditions are met

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a game using XNA and a part of the game involves collecting drops. I have this code below that detects intersection between the character and the item:

```
//Intersection Code, If the character intersects with the item while the item is showing, run below
if (alive && charRange.Intersects(itemRect))
{
   alive = false; //stop showing the item
   Inv.ItemGot(); //Call the ItemGot class, which adds the item to the inventory screen
}
```

Another class contains the `ItemGot()` method, and the code for that is below:

```
public void ItemGot()
{  // Called from the ItemList class...
   // Sets the background color to black when called
   btnItems[0] = new Panel();
   btnItems[0].BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Basically, when the character intersects with the item rectangle, the color of `btnItems[0]` should turn from `CornflowerBlue` (which I set up earlier) to `Black`. However, the color **does not** change when the method is called and I don't know why. My code seems to be correct and I've had peers confirm that for me.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in `ItemGot()` to confirm it's being called?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, `ItemGot()` is being called as btnItems[0] is filled

Comment: You initialize `btnItem[0]` in `ItemGot()`. Is `btnItem[0]` equal to `panel 1` ?

Comment: @user3093781 `btnItems[0]` **is** panel 1. Perhaps I should rephrase this: `btnItems[0]` 's color should change to `Black`.

Comment: You may need to add `btnItem[0]` to its parent control. For example, Form1.Controls.Add(btnItem[0]).

Comment: I added that, but still nothing happened. Could it be that you need an event handler for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `new Panel`, but never using it. It's likely you don't want to create a new one because you said the color is already set to `CornFlowerBlue`.

So, if you already have a `Panel` setup... ensure you add it to the `btnItems` list.  That way you can access it via `btnItems[0]`.

Comment: I got rid of the `btnItems[0] = new Panel();` but now I'm getting a NullReferenceException. Thing is though, I already initialized the panel array in the constructor.

Comment: I added details to my answer.