# Label text not updating

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public void ItemGot()
{
    number = number + 1;            //Increment by 1
    quantity.Text = ("x" + number); //Overwrite Text
    quantity.Refresh();             //Updates the text
}
```

Hello, I have this code above. When this method runs, the text of a label I set up earlier should change the text to the one i set below. However, its not doing it. Furthermore, by setting breakpoints in Visual Studio, I have determined that:

1. The method is being called,
2. Number is being incremented properly.

There should be NO reason why this not working, because the program is recognizing that `number` is increasing by one. My friend said a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930093/backcolor-is-not-changing-even-though-conditions-are-met). Still no help, and now that code is outdated. Please help!

**EDIT**: how I added the `quantity` label

First, I initialized it in the constructor: `public Label quantity;`

Then I did this: `quantity = new Label();`

Lastly, in another method, I gave the `quantity` the following properties:

```
quantity.Size = new Size(24, 24);
quantity.Text = ("x" + number);

quantity.Left = 48;

Controls.Add(quantity);
```

number is also in the constructor and is set to 0.

**EDIT 2**  : I'll Post my whole method

```
    public InventoryScreen()
    {
        btnItems = new Button();
        quantity = new Label();

        //call the methods for spawning the buttons 
        ButtonGenItems(cNumber, btnItems, quantity);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void InventoryScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    #region ButtonGenItems Method
    public void ButtonGenItems(int cNumber, Button btnItems,Label quantity)
    {
        int xPos = 126;
        int yPos = 25;

        for (int n = 0; n < 1; n++)
        {
            btnItems.Tag = n;
            btnItems.Size = new Size(48, 52);  //Button size X and Y
            btnItems.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;

            quantity.Size = new Size(24, 24);
            quantity.Text = ("x" + number);

            if (yPos > 60) // Five Buttons in one column
            {
                yPos = 25; //spawn position Y
                xPos = xPos + btnItems.Width + 10; //spacing X
            }

            btnItems.Left = xPos; //Start Button spawn at the Left side
            btnItems.Top = yPos;  //Start spawn at the top side

            quantity.Left = 48;
            quantity.Top = 60;

            yPos = yPos + btnItems.Height + 10;

            btnItems.Text = "Use";

            Controls.Add(btnItems); //place Buttons
            Controls.Add(quantity);

            // the Event of click Button
            //btnItems.Click += new System.EventHandler(ItemUse); //to be implimented
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public void ItemGot()
    {
        //*Interestingly, the program recognizes that 'number' is increasing by 1, but label won't update the text
        //Furthermore, pressing the actual button will trigger the text update, but simulating a buttonclick WONT DO ANYTHING 

        Console.WriteLine("Text should now increment by 1");  //Debugging to test method
        number = number + 1;            //Increment by 1
        quantity.Text = ("x" + number); //Overwrite Text
    }
}
```

**2.5** This is how the method is being called. This method is located in another class

```
public void Update(Vector2 pos)
        {
            this.position = pos; //get char position
            Inv = new InventoryScreen(); //create instance of object
            charRange = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, 64, 57); //create rectangle


            //Intersection Code, If the character intersects with the item while the item is showing, run below
            if (alive && charRange.Intersects(itemRect))
            {
                alive = false; //stop showing the item
                Inv.ItemGot(); //Call the ItemGot class, which adds the item to the inventory screen
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you can simplify `number = number + 1;` to `number++;`.

Comment: @GrantWinney `quantity` is a label added programmically, if that helps

Comment: @GrantWinney please see above for edits made

Comment: The code above should work. How do you call this method?

Comment: @Steve well i called it from a different class, so `Inv.ItemGot()` where Inv is the instance of the object that holds the `ItemGot()` method.

Comment: While researching, I found this thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c?rq=1). Could this be a Solution?

Comment: I have the suspect that you call that method on an instance of the form that is not displayed. Do you pass to the Inv instance a reference to the form where the label has been originally created?

Comment: @GrantWinney See edit 2, I posted my whole class

Comment: @GrantWinney Sorry, Please look at EDIT 2.5

Comment: Can you try adding --> quantity.refresh() into the update ItemGot() method?

Comment: @robnick thank you for your input, unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you have already open/showed form(instance of class `InventoryScreen`) with your label when you calling `Update` method, But...

Inside of method `Update` you creating a new instance of `InventoryScreen`, and calling function `ItemGot` with this new instance of form.

I think you need to pass reference of your current instance of `InventoryScreen` in method `Update`, then use that reference for calling `ItemGot` method

```
public void Update(Vector2 pos, InventoryScreen invscreen)
{
    this.position = pos;
    charRange = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, 64, 57);

    if (alive && charRange.Intersects(itemRect))
    {
        alive = false;
        invscreen.ItemGot(); 
    }
}
```